# Date error in writing to excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using the [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) function to write a few files loaded from databases into an Excel spreadsheet.  The function being used is the following:

```
def country_reports(countries):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('country_reports.xlsx')
    for country in countries:
        df = report(country)
        df.to_excel(writer, country)
    writer.save()
```

The `report(country)` method just returns a `DataFrame` of relevant data for that country.  I would like to run this report for multiple countries, and then have each country's data represented in its own tab in Excel.  This would normally be pretty simple, but I have dates earlier than 1900 in some of my DataFrames, which makes it impossible for me to write to Excel, since it throws an error:

> ValueError: Year not supported by Excel: 1861.

I had no issues when writing these files as CSVs, so I was curious if there would be some way to create an excel file that had multiple tabs represented by CSVs?  If not, is there another way around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need the to show the dates in Excel?  If that's the case, could you just convert to a string, something like this.

```
df['date_col'] = df['date_col'].apply(lambda x: x.date().isoformat())
```

If you actually need to work with dates in Excel, it's probably best to separate month / day / year into separate columns, something like this:

```
df['year'] = df['date_col'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
df['day'] = df['date_col'].apply(lambda x: x.day)
df['month'] = df['date_col'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
```